# How to get values for object in didChangeObject:(id)anObject (NSfetchedResultsController)

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How can i access the object actual values in this fetchedResultsController delegate method ?

I would want to set the section of the indexpath for rows to delete/change according to values of the object, as the table has multiple datasources

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
  atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath 
{
....get objects value, e.g. myEntity.city 
}
```

Now i know that the object will always be of class myEntity (at least ultimately, not sure what exactly "anObject" refers to), but obviously the compiler complains when i want to set an instance of myEntity *anEntity = anObject;

My workaround has been to put data for each section into arrays, and do all work in the
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: where i know which section was called and i just need to access the indexpath.row. Drawback is i have to reload the arrays after each change and can not directly work with the fetchedResultsController.

EDIT:
Accepted answer works fine, this shortcut seems to work too for my purpose:

```
NSString *aString = [anObject valueForKey:@"city"];
```

Comment: myEntity *anEntity = (myEntity *)anObject;

Comment: that looks quite reasonable indeed, can not run that immediately but looks like it should work and will be happy to then accept as an answer. Cheers for superfast response!

Comment: @Wain: you should just expand that into an answer.  @wadi:  You just need to cast `anObject` to the type you want (Entity) and then use it like a normal instance of that object.  Some people like to add assertions like `NSAssert([anObject isKindOfClass:[Entity class]],…)` or even, `NSAssert(anObject == The_One_Object_I_Think_I'm_Observing, …)`

Comment: @AaronGolden you convinced me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does complain, but it's only a warning because you haven't told it what to expect. It's as simple as:

```
myEntity *anEntity = (myEntity *)anObject;
```

That said, you do need to be sure that it's the correct class, so it pays to add a little protection:

```
if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[myEntity class]) {
    myEntity *anEntity = (myEntity *)anObject;
    // do stuff
} else {
    NSLog(@"Panic / cry / plead");
}
```

Comment: just saw in the logs that what i tried before works too, had wrong keys so didnt notice before:
NSString *aString = [anObject valueForKey:@"city"];